# Meteor HTTP GET Request - 'Socket Hangup' Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In my Meteor app, I am making outbound HTTP GET requests on an interval like such:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  try {
    var request = Meteor.http.call("GET", <url>, {
      params: <params>,
      timeout: <timeout>
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    request = undefined;
  }
  if (request.statusCode === 200) {
    // handle the response
    ...
  }
}, 10000);
```

If I let this run for a few minutes, I start getting errors logged to console via the `catch` block: `Error: socket hang up`.

What is causing these errors and how can they be mitigated? According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867185/socket-hang-up-error-during-request), the request needs to be told to `.end();`, but I'm not sure if this is correct or how to do this in Meteor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `this.response.end();` I use it in my router listening to webhooks and it works fine

Comment: where would that line go in the example above? no matter where i put it, I get this: ` TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' of undefined`

Comment: @JonCursi apologies, you should be doing `request.end()`

Comment: I tried that too, no luck. On exactly what line above should I put that? Maybe I'm inserting it in the wrong spot?

Comment: @JonCursi I'd put it after you handle the response inside the `if` statement

Comment: no luck, doesn't seem like making a synchronous HTTP request like I have above creates an `end` method on the `request` object that I can use. Getting `[Object object] has no method 'end'`

Comment: @JonCursi are you using ngrok to test it out? are you seeing any status 200's in there?